# Putting your own question on Owner-Hold

Tags: discussion

> Edits are put in blockquotes

---

Sometimes you have a question and not sure how to form the question. This can result in a bad question but in your own eyes it could be okay.

This can happen when you don't know much on the subject. But it is also true for those who need to step out of their own discipline and right into a matter which is new to them.

As a side note and wrapped around the Stack Exchanges, people new to this website often need to learn how to write questions and most are willing to do so. This feature-request is for the above as wel as Stack Exchange newbies who already have experienced that rotten downvoting.

This feature, however, has nothing to do against downvoting. It has to do with qualifying yourself as OP and saving all other user's, longing for quality, their precious time. Stack Echange in itself isn't about down-voting either, is has the same purpose, i.e.: improve yourself.

> Expecting users to even trust that self-deletion is reversible is bad design, besides being unrealistic.

---

**Why are we here**

Questions can be of several sorts, e.g.:

1. You know about the subject but need some clarification.
2. You know little but enough to clarify your question well enough.
3. You know nothing and search around the net and you are over-informed about everything but the subject. This to the power of two since you do not know terminology.
4. You simply don't have english as you native language and picked it up due to programming.

Stack Overflow is meant to be for quality. This goes for answers aswell for questions. Therefore it does need to squeeze out those 'bad questions', as it is happening right now. Shouldn't change.

The Stack Exchange is aiming to be a high level (academical) resource platform to improve internet's resources and by that, you! High level resource platforms need to have a high level toolshelve which will benefit everyone.

> By academical I meant university level. At least to indicate a high level of quality. Not classes as Travis J pointed out to me.

---

**Example:**

You're working on a project and get stuck so you seek around on the net, in books and/or your own notes. Still in the mists since you can't seek for `while( 1 --> 0 )` and you don't know how the operator `-->` is called.

When having a real problem and not the `-->` and you don't know why something is happening by what reason you start writing your question. It looks good and you post, get feedback in comments and even get an answer which get up-voted.

However the question lacks almost everything like correct terminology, doesn't provide a correct 'working' example. You get down-voted and even more. You start your edit of the question but while you do that you still get downvoted although it is clear the question is not suited. Again, it is not about the down-voting but about improving yourselve in asking a good question which will benefit everyone.

While editting people are still reading the question, missing out those questions they can answer as those are well-written. This will make two errors on the Stack Exchange, one gets down-voted but doesn't deserve it while another one misses the attention that does deserve it. Both errors can be prevented.

OP posted the question because (s)he could be in an unknown field already, a reason to ask in itself. This can raise more problems for the OP due to answers/comments which needs to be researched first before continuing.

While the OP is busy to improve the answer time passes and (s)he has other responsibilities to take care of.

(S)he can't delete the question since an answer is given and up-voted. Therefore it stays visible all the time, messing up everybodies time and even getting more down-votes a.k.a. punishment for a bad question while (s)he is busy to improve. The punishment is seated in loosing priviliges (s)he has earned already. It has been proven (s)he is good enough to have those but (s)he may not anymore because (s)he got frustrated on an operator that *doesn't even exists but does compile* and is unsearchable.

---

**Active list**

In attempts to improve the question - seeying it after writting down does make it more clear to most people - the question gets 'bumped' in the active list. Again a possibility all other people looses time by giving the attention since they expect an improvement. Also they have sympathy for the OP but now they get annoyed.

An Owner-Hold, until prevoked by the OP, can be left out of this list until (s)he unholds it again and people can read it.

---

**Other benefits**

A feature like this will give the OP the ability to develop in asking questions more easily. Actually it will encourage those who are longing for it. It can force people to be critical about themselves without a negative pressure such a ban-risk gives when using a delete/undelete construction when, and only when, it is available.

Asking a question as usual rather then having to 'publish' first, as Vijay suggested, will keep the usage as we have already. Keeping it as it is will still encourage people to write a good question 'in one go' as the heavily editted answer of Kevin Voom suggested.

> In addition to inexperienced users who attract downvotes, it can also be useful when a the question of a more experienced user is misinterpreted and attracts answers missing the point.
>
> Putting one's own question on hold would let users take responsibility for fixing the deficiencies that have been mentioned in comments, without feeling too pressured. It should have the same effects as having it "closed," plus:
>
> - Voting should be locked for the entire page, including answers.
> - No votes to delete.
> - No third-party edits. An inexperienced user trying to make revisions will be blindsided by any other changes, even helpful ones.

---

**Implementations**

To keep functionallity of the up/down-vote system at high-activity tags, a delay to put on Owner-Hold of 15 minutes should be sufficient enough.

Putting a (mass) timer on all (or grouped) owner-holds can unhold all once a week or so, reviewing can continue while owner-hold isn't allowed anymore due to the forced unhold.

Alternatively; Owner-Holds can be automatically deleted after a month or whatever of inactivity since the OP lost his interrest in the question, cleans up jitter - making use of a nasty humain property e.g. laziness.

*(next needs to be worked out into a usable feature though)*
A side-feature, new to SE and a lot of down-votes on all/first question, a pop-up rises telling about owner-hold privilige which helps you to improve your skill in asking good questions.

Less 'active'-list activity.

> When a question is Owner-Holded giving answrs should be locked down. However given answers should still be editable since they are participating with the question.

---

**Preventing misusage**

A little, not too high - rep is needed. New people need to know the principle of the Stack Exchange first. Also the heavy down-voting is a must for a lot of people, since they are used to forums and don't want to read a FAQ. A bigger reputation would backfire on some of the purposes i.e. those learning Stack Exchange and on those longing to improving themselves.

---

## Summary:

- When a question already has more then one or one up-voted answer, you *can't* delete/undelete your post.
- Facilitating an (academical) resource platform should have a high standard tool shelve. It just works easier.
- An Owner-Hold can save everybodies time by not reading it since it is *knowingly* by OP not interresting/open/qualifying at the moment.
- An Owner-Hold question can be left out of the 'active'-list untill unholded.
- To prevent people from posting to quick and putting it on Owner-Hold a small reputation could be added before OP can use it.
- Due to comments and answers the OP can get more insight in what to seek for to improve the question (or find an answer).
- A feature like this will give the OP the ability to develop in asking questions more easily. Actually it will encourage those who are longing for it. It can force people to be critical about themselves without a negative pressure such a ban-risk gives.
- Asking a question as usual will still encourage people to write a good question 'in one go'.

Comment: You can delete the question, fix it, then open it again if needed. Or of course just make sure your question is properly asked, can't be that difficult.

Comment: @KevinVoorn I hope that last sentence was sarcastic.

Comment: Would like to hear more ideas/opinions about the matter from people in favour of this. So the subject can develop

Comment: @brainoverflow: Why not also from those seeing all the downsides, and thus adamantly opposed?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Didn't I take those into consideration while updating the above?

Comment: @Deduplicator: advicing to hide the question isn't a valid answer to my statement above. Never said it should have been hidden. That's more or less what KevinVoom said. An [On-hold] is visible too. Yet an [Owner-hold] is marked as 'am working on it, read it in the mean while'

Comment: As for Potatoswatter: Forgot to add his input, will do that too. Maybe it will show why some need an [Owner-hold].

Comment: @Deduplicator: Do you mean those not knowing what the problem is or the adamantly sarcasm? The high vote of KevinVoom doesn't say anything as it misses the entire point of the above (even before the first edit).

Comment: If this were implemented, what would prevent it from being abused? It is very similar to a moderator lock. Further, if there are answers it is not fair to those users to radically change the question. This is basically a workaround for delete.

Comment: The deletion is a workaround for this. Let me ask you this: "When someone posts a question and get answered, wat will prevent the OP or any other with the ability to change the question entirly with even other tags and another subject so it should be moved to another site of the stack exchange?"

Answer (score 41):

If your question receives downvotes and you want to fix your question, you can delete your question and fix the issues (use, for example, notepad) while nobody is able to see / vote (users with more then 10K reputation will be able to see your question, but not cast votes, answer or comment). You can then undelete your own question again by clicking `undelete` below your question and put the fixes in.

[image]

You can only undelete your own question if other users didn't delete it (so you'll have to be the person deleting it). When you have more reputation you can always vote to close your own question. Keep in mind you cannot delete your own question if it has multiple answers, or if there is a single answer with at least upvote.

Comment: People with a high reputation can still view the question though.

Comment: @brainoverflow Yes they can (10K) - but they cannot do anything (answer, comment, vote, ...).

Comment: @KevinVoorn you also may want to mention that once a question has multiple answers, or a single answer with an upvote, self-deletion is not possible without moderator assistance.

Comment: @psubee2003 Edited, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Questioners cannot edit while the post is deleted.  Your advice should probably include a recommendation to edit off-line so they can quickly copy/paste after undeleting the post.

Comment: @HansPassant edited

Comment: Drafts are unwanted. Don't know why exactly but can imagine the tons of 'never-will-be-published-storaged-data'. This can be hold back by the obligation of first posting and not 'semi-drafting' for one hour. Although an hour sounds short, I think that would be even too long regarding the original point of view.

Comment: @brainoverflow I'm not exactly sure what the problem is tbh. You have to ask questions that are of good quality anyway, so it's kinda your own "fault" that you're getting downvotes, and SO shouldn't be providing tools to fix it *after* you asked the question. The only way of improving them without losing reputation is deleting them and fix them, so using a draft is basically your only go-to. But as I said, focus more on asking quality questions instead :-) Btw, you can delete files, so the "tons of data" is a bit exaggerated for some text files of a couple kb.

Comment: @KevinVoorn: Ask a good question in the first place: When you have a problem you stumbled upon other problems can arise while fixing. These can be problems you coudn't imagine as you are already within a field you don't know - or you wouldn't have to ask in the first place. In one shot, indeed better. But life is always something else. - Ofcourse SO should provide tools to do so, SO is the marketing tool for their business, so facilitate it, IMHO. btw: illegal data-storage won't be deleted by 'OPs' but that goes offtopic and we should leave that alone.

Comment: Keeping the question visible for others too see, and being able to downvote it, I couldn't care less. It's a mentality thing. My mentallity, honour, pride - whatever you want to call it. I messed up, may I be able to correct myself?

Comment: @brainoverflow It's a good thing to correct yourself, so yes: Ofcourse you may. But that also means you'll *have* to use the method I explained :P

Comment: @KevinVoorn: That's too easy ;)

Comment: Doesn't the act of deleting too many times get you some short of punishement?

Comment: @Malavos: Exactly my point. Believe it is with a **very** low number like 2 or 3.

Comment: @Malavos deleted questions will count towards a question ban, however you're not permanently deleting it: When you undelete your question it will not count towards a question ban because the question is no longer deleted (note: There is no hard evidence of this - but it seems it works this way).

Comment: Anyway, if deleting the question counts towards a question ban, and we have no information of undeleting it will not count towards it, it seems to me that deleting the question is a bad choice.

Comment: Also, if you made a bad question in the first place, you probably received some downvotes. It's probably more interesting to delete your question altogether, and improve it unto a new one. But if that gets a ban, 
Alexei Levenkov answer is a better way to deal with it.

Comment: @Malavos My answer is based on advise given by diamond moderators, so I think it's safe to say that undeleted questions do not count towards a question ban. It might be more interesting to delete a question and make a new one instead, but keep in mind this means you will have a deleted question which **will for sure** count towards a ban.

Comment: @KevinVoorn I see, but until we have some sort of confirmation, I would not risk doing neither of them, and I would follow the answer below.

Comment: @Malavos That might be a good solution however it does not answer the askers question, as he was wondering about a way to lock downvotes.

Comment: My bad, Kevin. I though the question was:
"Would it be a good idea to have next to the delete button, an owner-hold button so the OP can pull back his question until fixed. Telling people he has noticed it and is busy with improving the question. If it is a good idea, should people still be able to downvote, comment or answer it?" Which is a suggestion, which this answer does not state anything about OP suggestion.

Comment: @Malavos Well as you can see, there are currently 3 people who disagree and 41 who agree, so I think I addressed the concerns of OP very well. Anyway, let's stop commenting here, it's getting nowhere and only adds noise.

Comment: @KevinVoorn: Did not ask to lock downvotes at all. Maybe I was unlcear about that, my apologies.

Comment: @KevinVoorn: All questions count for determining question ban / rate limiting. Though one which is deleted probably weighs stronger against one.

Answer (score 7):

I'd advice against hiding the question if it is high traffic tag like C#/Java, but instead *actively* participate in improving it.

Why:

- high traffic tags will drown your question relatively quickly. Yes, edit bumps it in "active" view, but still for relatively short amount of time.
- majority of questions never get improved or seemingly even looked at by original poster making most people downvote and ignore.
- quickly answering to comment will keep answerer engaged with your question instead of going to downvote more random ones instead.

Assuming you start with question that at least you believe make sense and get downvote - try to guess why and add *comment* yourself like "am I getting downvote because ... (some reasonable explantaion)?" - make sure to *not* phrase it like "*@#@ dovnwoters don't understand and don't leave comments" as it is not likely to bring productive conversation.

Edit in answers to comments about your post AND reply with "@WhateverName updated the question with XXXXX, hopefully making it clear".

I would not downvote post where OP is engaged into really improving the question. If question have no chance to survive (blatantly off-topic or completely opinion-based) I'd simply vote to close possibly with comment.

Comment: Time can be an factor in this case. Time in the sence of 1) researching, 2) thinking over, 3) other activities/responsibilities, But in all other cases I would agree with you.

Answer (score 5):

Fantastic idea.

In addition to inexperienced users who attract downvotes, it can also be useful when a the question of a more experienced user is misinterpreted and attracts answers missing the point.

Putting one's own question on hold would let users take responsibility for fixing the deficiencies that have been mentioned in comments, without feeling too pressured. It should have the same effects as having it "closed," plus:

- Voting should be locked for the entire page, including answers.
- No votes to delete.
- No third-party edits. An inexperienced user trying to make revisions will be blindsided by any other changes, even helpful ones.

An owner-hold should have a time limit, maybe 24 hours. Ideally it's hidden from search results. After that, it gets reopened to criticism and deletion.

Since the owner is getting temporary privileges for taking responsibility, already-closed questions should also be eligible for owner holds. (Perhaps not duplicates, though.) When the hold is released, it goes back to the normal process, leading to reopening or deletion.

I don't buy into arguments about user behavior based on the site rules and gaming strategies, because most users aren't aware of all the rules and wouldn't try to apply a strategy anyway. Seriously, someone who gets question-banned, yet stays around, is an outlier.

Expecting users to even trust that self-deletion is reversible is bad design, besides being unrealistic.

Comment: Hmm, I think if votes are prevented, it should not be possible to remove owner-hold without an edit (that bumps the question and triggers the votes deserved)

Comment: @BenVoigt The principle I'm going for is that owner-hold gives the owner free reign to revise the question without interference, but only for a limited time. So, any edits would have to be approved by the owner. (I've seen a few cases of edit conflicts, and it's always confusing to the novice asker.)

Comment: I meant an edit by the owner.  I'm against the hold becoming a way to stop downvotes if no improvements are actually made.  So if the owner doesn't submit an edit, the hold shouldn't be reversed/reopened after 24 hours, it should proceed forward to normal closure (which lifts the voting hold).

Comment: @BenVoigt Oh, of course. Open => owner-hold => expires => regular-hold (a.k.a. closed). Actually I don't think it should be reopened automatically after 24 hours even with an edit. There should be a big, unmistakeable "remove hold" button to provide confirmation, maybe even an alert box after every edit during a hold. (But it should also be clear that once released, another hold isn't allowed.)

Comment: Actually, all answers must stay modifiable as normal for their owners (you don't really want to stop them from correcting their answers or deleting them if they don't get anywhere, do you?), they need a notification when it ends, and mis-use needs a painful penalty. Actually, it's far too prone to mis-use.

Comment: The 24 limit should be a longer time since SO is for profesionals **and** enthousiasts. The latter don't have always the time. Maybe a week so it span a weekend. Wouldn't mind those not seeying it in the active-list anyway. A limit should definetly be their.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a feature for this, it is called delete. You can edit when a post is deleted, all comments, voting, and answers are locked, and it does not show up anywhere.

With the self-hold users would essentially be allowed to lock their own posts similar to the moderator ability, except they would still be allowed to edit only their own content. While this may have been intended to help a few new users, it is low hanging fruit for being abused. Further, it basically removes the community from being able to moderate the post.

I disagree that Stack Overflow is an academic institution. Stack Overflow is not here to teach you how to write your first for loop, or write "Hello World" in every language that you can think of. That is simply not on topic.

While it is here as a repository of knowledge, the knowledge recorded is that of an artisan, not a student. If people want to be educated, they should attend classes. If you get stuck on a unique problem you can reproduce, post on it on Stack Overflow and the community will gladly help you through it.

Comment: You **CAN'T** delete youw question. Read the high up-voted question again, and do it carefully. Boom, there it is written down why you **CAN'T** use that.

Comment: @brainoverflow - You can delete your question so long as there is not an upvoted answer. If the answer addresses the question and the community agrees with it, but the OP feels that their question *deserves* something different then the question was not straightforward enough. At that point, it is too late. Users should not be coddled into thinking they can post poor quality and then everything will be okay with an undo button. There are consequences for posting low quality, and those consequences are in place with the goal of motivating users to post higher quality content.

Comment: Think you underestimate users. The entire point of workflow on SO is based upon trust and it turns out the majority is fair in the usage of the SE. When after an Owner-hold the question is still not good or isn't lifted up in quality, down-voting can continue.

Comment: It is sad to see the narrow mindedness - in general -  about new features and see directly disagrements while the only tag is 'discussion'. A discussion means IMHO just as it says, discuss the features. All in favour and all against. So then we **all** can decide if it will be a good feature or not. Unfortunatly some think we can do it like this and so decide it should be so for all people. Can say the 33 up-votes are massively lower then the 39 of the answer about the 'delete' thing. It valuable enough to discuss it.

Comment: But hey, you can delete so that's good enough. How about: "You can post bad questions", sounds not good too. But you can, so you must do it like that.

Comment: @brainoverflow - Do you think your tone here adds to your argument, or detracts from it?

Comment: I definitely do not underestimate users. I have just seen a lot of abuse, and a lot of entitlement from users who post low quality content. The users I keep in mind are the ones who contribute actively because lately everyone seems so quick to point a finger at them. Highly active contributors do not want to spend a lot of time helping to fix a post about something which is more than likely rudimentary.

Comment: Oh, sarcasm is one way and meaning towards me. is okay. Have fun.

Comment: @brainoverflow - Sarcasm? It was not sarcastic at all. Ad hominem attacks such as calling this answer "stupid" or editing out your insults after you post a comment is flat out rude and adds nothing to this discussion.

Comment: Down-voting at random is an abuse to. Why aposing against a feature that can possibly be something to reduce abuse.

Comment: However '(acadamic) resource platform' doesn't equal an academical institute. Also an academy isn't only for student (maybe a language thing here: In my language an academy and university are the same thing). SO is free, who is mad enough to pay for this all? Who is exploiting me, may facilitate me.

Comment: @brainoverflow - I don't think that downvoting is random though. I see you have asked some well received questions, they didn't get randomly downvoted. Overall they look like questions with clear problem statements which were answerable (and contain answers). Content which gets downvoted is often from the users who simply post at the first sign of trouble. The post was lost from the second it was committed, with full disregard to all the material given in the form of related/duplicate suggestions on the side or the entire walkthrough in the help center for posting on topic content.

Comment: Some where editted and one is in the 'queue of delete', Which is a horrible question I may say. Workin on that. It makes me feel uneasy due to the question-ban. That's what this post is about.

Comment: @brainoverflow - The word academic implies that there is a student and a teacher. The teacher will give lecture by way of tedious example and explanation. While some great answers here could be lectures, the overall nature is not to train someone with no experience how to be a programmer because that would be repeating all of the common information available all over the internet. There is no need to document how to write hello world on Stack Overflow. Resource platform (knowledge repository) is a phrase that fits here, however the word academic really does not fit.

Comment: Also, not to be superfluous, but for future reference OP means "Original Poster" (which is you) :)

Comment: hehe, I know, thought original post would be clear enough.

Answer (score -1):

Actually its all about `Learning to write question`

At first its like a `Speed Breaker` for everyone initially

```
                      Negative side Bad Question
```

- You get down voted
- you get banned

  ```
                    Positive side of Bad question
  ```
- On deleting own Post you will be awarded with stackoverflow `Peer Pressure` Batch
- Also remove you from `Ban`
- All above points will teach you `How to write question`

---

```
                             Solutions Till Now
```

1. `Don't Post Question If Not sure`
2. Else `@Kevin Voorn` above method: How to delete bad question, then update  question  , then again undelete.
3. Else `@Alexei Levenkov` above method  : `Root cause the question` and Find out why people are down voting and `repair` question accordingly.
4. Else `Stackoverflow` should come up with functionality called

**`PUBLISH` : the person keeps editing post for some days**

WITHOUT being authored By field Experts

and when he feels ,the post has become nice question the he can `PUBLISH` it.

Comment: 1) How do you earn points on deleting your question other then restoring those you already had? 2) Speed-breaking can be done by adding the privilige to put on `[Owner-Hold]` / `Publish`

Comment: The ban is something I do not wish to risk when trying to upgrade myself. It can be a punishment for trying to improve yourself.

Comment: @brainoverflow thank you to point out.I have corrected the post.And we only earn badge for deleting post with negative votes.

Comment: 1 )  ill-logically : [Owner-Hold] / Publish can `Really` be a speed breaker
But
2 ) Logically : [Owner-Hold] / Publish 2.1 ) it will `force` you to write `complex` questions in`simple` manner. 2.2) That every one can understand and use general words while explaining.2.3) It will force you to do `more research` on what actually you want and not 10 things in just one  question.And if `many people understand you question` you will get `lots of answers` for it `not just one`.

Comment: Ban really can be punishment while upgrading ourself .But it is just one time bridge. 100% of stackoverflow users have gone through 'Ban' 'BUT ONLY ONCE' after that we actually 'LEARN' how to write question.

Comment: I don't think anywhere near 100% of users have gone through a ban.

Comment: Think I did misunderstood the term 'speed-breaking'. A question with ten questions in it should be downvoted 56 times if the user has a reputation of 111 (=me at the moment of writing).

Comment: @Ben yes you are right.`Not all users` have been through `Ban`.I should have used word `MOSTLY` that dosen't include all users

Answer (score -1):

> @brainoverflow: Why not also from those seeing all the downsides, and thus adamantly opposed? –  Deduplicator

Seeying a downside doesn't mean the sight is true, right or correct.

**Took into consideration:**

1. > You can delete the question, fix it, then open it again if needed

   - You can't delete when a (false) answer is given which is up-voted or have more answer. Such as this meta-question. The most up-voted answer is not correct, it fails in answering the subject and while answering, it lacks to explain why that should work. It only explains why it **can't** work. Stricly taken, those up-votes should be considered in favour of the suggestion.
2. > Questioners cannot edit while the post is deleted. Your advice should probably include a recommendation to edit off-line so they can quickly copy/paste after undeleting the post. –  Hans Passant

   - Don't see why this would be something to see as opposed. It is just saying the answer is incomplete.
3. > I'm not exactly sure what the problem is tbh. You have to ask questions that are of good quality anyway, so it's kinda your own "fault" that you're getting downvotes, and SO shouldn't be providing tools to fix it after you asked the question. The only way of improving them without losing reputation is deleting them and fix them, so using a draft is basically your only go-to. But as I said, focus more on asking quality questions instead :-)

   - Your own 'fault'. It happens. Again it is not about being down-voted but on

     > 'focus more on asking quality questions instead'.
4. > Also, if you made a bad question in the first place, you probably received some downvotes. It's probably more interesting to delete your question altogether, and improve it unto a new one. But if that gets a ban, Alexei Levenkov answer is a better way to deal with it.

   - Finally, one comment oposing against. However seeying other comment of Malavos, I conclude it is an argument against the oposing people.
5. '...3 people who disagree and 41...'

   - right. I may not downvote, since it is a topic I created that's strange. That said: 4 against 41, how many others who agree with me can't downvote here? This answer isn't correct, it doesn't go into the topic which has been addressed *at all*. Delete/undelete is a way to do what I described as a 'work-around' but still, question-ban and not **able to delete** when... stands tall.
6. > majority of questions never get improved or seemingly even looked at by original poster making most people downvote and ignore.

   - Although true, what does this have to do with questions that are being improved?
7. > quickly answering to comment will keep answerer engaged with your question instead of going to downvote more random ones instead.

   - Doens't stand against, comment quote: "6 Time can be an factor in this case. Time in the sence of 1) researching, 2) thinking over, 3) other activities/responsibilities, But in all other cases I would agree with you."
8. > I would not downvote post where OP is engaged into really improving the question. If question have no chance to survive (blatantly off-topic or completely opinion-based) I'd simply vote to close possibly with comment.

   - Some people, not he, will down-vote just to down-vote while seeking for reasons to down-vote (all or not in line with the rules) and never came back. I quote: "majority of questions never get improved or seemingly even looked at by original poster...", or un-down-vote I'd add.
9. > I meant an edit by the owner. I'm against the hold becoming a way to stop downvotes if no improvements are actually made. So if the owner doesn't submit an edit, the hold shouldn't be reversed/reopened after 24 hours, it should proceed forward to normal closure (which lifts the voting hold).

   - Something said which I agree with. If no edits are made, down-vote it. This could be done by automatically [close] it, even without taking others their time to close. Not even to put it in the active list. (Not all topics are high active).
10. > Actually, all answers must stay modifiable as normal for their owners (you don't really want to stop them from correcting their answers or deleting them if they don't get anywhere, do you?), they need a notification when it ends, and mis-use needs a painful penalty. Actually, it's far too prone to mis-use.

    - Maybe I should have implemented this one more. Good point. It's not opposing what is said here.

**Conclusion:**

Most in favour but some with additive solutions or other ideas that are considered already in the OP.