# User voted to close his own question. Should that trigger an automatic delete?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close

I saw a user who asked this question [i wanna know more this Fibonacci's operating Principles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66270493/i-wanna-know-more-this-fibonaccis-operating-principles#66270493) who then voted to close his own question.

What results from a person closing their own question rather than just deleting it? Are there some question/answer rep points possibly awarded on such question (Not a case here... but potentially...) Why would a person vote to close their own question?

Are the impacts on the close vote queue and re-open queue review negligible?

I wonder about that particular use case... Should it instead automatically trigger a delete of the question?

I think if a user wants to close its own question... It is equal to delete it. But I may miss some aspects too.

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is exactly? Is it: 1) Why can users vote to close their own posts? 2) Should that be allowed? 3) Should it trigger deletion of the post? Also, please edit the title of this question. Facts are fun, but they aren't questions.

Comment: Good point @cigien... Should that be allowed: yes no prob. I was wondering about the unusual use case which *maybe* no one thought possible before. Now, I am ambivalent about the pertinence of my question here. It must be a so rare use case.. Does it make it negligable?

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong with asking "why is this even possible?". Just edit the question title and body to make that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post has an answer [When is it OK to delete your own question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281849/when-is-it-ok-to-delete-your-own-question) that has some good points about not deleting a question.

Rather than automatically trigger a delete instead offer that as an option should a person try to close their own question. That way a person gets to make the decision as to whether to just close the question or to actually delete it.

What would be interesting would be to allow a person who creates a question to also be able to close it themselves just as a person can also delete it by themselves. For instance if someone finds out their post is a duplicate, they could just go ahead and close as duplicate. [Why do you have the option to vote to close your own question? Why would you ever do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345429/why-do-you-have-the-option-to-vote-to-close-your-own-question-why-would-you-eve)

If a question is closed, it can still be seen by anyone, anyone can edit it, and anyone can ask for it to be reopened.

Closing a question can discourage voting on the question, giving the person asking it breathing space to think and edit the question. At the same time people can give feedback through comments.

However Owner Hold has been proposed in the past as an alternative to deleting a question. See this discussion [Putting your own question on Owner-Hold](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284262/putting-your-own-question-on-owner-hold) with an answer that begins

> There is already a feature for this, it is called delete. You can edit
> when a post is deleted, all comments, voting, and answers are locked,
> and it does not show up anywhere.

Comment: To delete our own question is pretty intuitive. I have often done it myself on questions and on answers. But a to "vote to close" as more impacts, such as the review queues... And that process is highly un-intuitive for new users... Review queues access is at 500 rep. Before that, a user just doesn't know anything about it.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette How much or how little a user knows isn't necessarily directly proportional to rep. It's more a matter of time spent on the site interacting with the site and reading the materials available on the site. If a person who posts a question has the ability to close it by themselves then it doesn't go to a review, it just gets closed. A reopen would go to a review which provides a way to find out if the changes corrected the problems with the post.

Comment: Okay... I quite agree to that. I am just putting my 2 cents about something new I just noticed. Still, I wonder the possibility of a user wishing to temporarily... say "disable" his question... And hit the "CLOSE" instead of the "DELETE" like we would do as experienced user. As you certainly know, there is a lot of non-english people who potentially could confuse on it. So in practice, if you vote to CLOSE your question, you can not REOPEN it when you are ready.. .like the delete way. But I will accept your answer because I feel like cutting hairs in four.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette You should edit your question a bit or it's going to start collecting more downvotes. I can do it if you like.  A change to the title and a bit of reworking some of the text along the lines of "I noticed this behavior which seemed strange and should this behavior automatically trigger this system action instead?"

Answer (score 1):

Guiding users to delete content sounds like a bad idea.

I don't think there is serious misunderstanding of what "close" and "delete" mean even for new users and I'm pretty sure number of "self-close" vote is very small to deserve any additional work even if there is some value in it (I'm not interested in the exact numbers as I don't think it should be implemented even if there is enough close votes, but the feature request can be improved by actual usage numbers).

At least half of close reasons are not about "this is not suitable for SO ever" but either "need to be improved by OP" or "resolved in a way that answers should not be added to this post". Only "belongs to another SE site" and blatant recommendations requests deserve deletion (and many recommendation requests actually fine if reworded to follow rules).

Guiding users toward removal of the content imply that it is something that SO/SE actually encourages. This is not the case as it is generally preferable to improve content rather than remove.

And guiding new users toward deletion of the content may push them toward question ban, especially if that was for a question that was  "resolved in a way unlikely to help future users" with an answer.

Overall I would prefer users to be guided toward close, improve and re-open rather than delete and re-ask.

Answer (score -4):

I think, no - if the user has the intent to delete the question, but he can not, it has a reason (mostly, to not lose the work of the answerers). If the user has no intent to delete his question, but wants to close it on some reason, then he gets his vote to close it.

I think, what could be done better:

1. Users might get decisive close votes to their own questions, if they want to close it on some reason.
2. The most likely cause of the intent that the user wants to delete his own question, is that it was deeply downvoted. Currently, deeply downvoted questions can be disassociated from the user's profile, but it requires the /contact form (i.e. a CM can do it manually). This process could (should) be automatized.

Comment: I think that the down-votes on a post aren't a reason sufficient to dissociate the account from a post. Dissociating the account is an action rarely taken, and for a better reason.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Large amount of obviously unfair downvotes (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45818964/1783163)) imho qualify. I never did it, but I never read that the team had rejected such an ask.

Comment: I think I read something on Meta Stack Exchange (not a question) about dissociating an account from posts, but I cannot find the link right now.

Comment: I just found [an answer from animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288467/225647) on this very site, which says: _The only time questions ever really get dissociated from an account is when they're of fairly good quality or useful to future visitors and the user, for whatever reason, doesn't want their name on it anymore._ It seems to exclude that posts with many down-votes are dissociated from the account used to post them.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Possible, but it is not clear to me that it is about the /contact post disassociations. It is from 2015.

Comment: [JNat's answer in 2018 on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315332/241919) is more updated: "*None of this (deletion, redaction, and disassociation) can be used to lift a posting block by the system — if you are blocked from posting new questions or answers, please refer to Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account? and Why are answers no longer being accepted from my account? for guidance on how to lift the block.*"